# Why do the same coding files keep being uploaded to my branches?

Tags: git

So for uni, we students have been supplied with a gitlab account to upload our coding homework and the way we were supposed to upload is to create an additional branch for each homework. So I did that, however every time I push a new branch, I notice that all my previous homework files from previos branches have also been uploaded. At the moment I have solved that with :

git reset

, however could someone maybe explain why this is happening (sorry I am very new to git) and also if my way is the correct way to resolve the issue?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Because you are starting new branches from older ones? So you get to keep the history of the branch that you are starting from. Perhaps you should be starting from a _different_ template branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new branch in git, it is actually based on the current state you had checked out before. That's how git works. Branches are actually intended to later get merged back into the main branch (often called `master`) and therefore also contain all changes that where made in this branch before forking the branch of. So yeah what you are doing with git reset is wrong and I would suggest just keeping each homework in a folder inside one single branch.